# Accessing a QList<QObject*> from QML with Qt 4.7

Tags: qt, model, qml, qt4.7

I have a QList list for a primitive logging part. Basically it looks something like this:
QList appLog -> appLogEntry -> NfcLogEntry -> QString url + QString uid

I want to expose my model to QML and access the url and uid and other intermediate variables. I have read and gone through several articles, but I think I still have my confusions over the topic. What would be the best way to do it?

Anyone can help me with an example or a code snippet that works on Qt 4.7 and QML 1.0 (I'm developing for a N9)?

Comment: *SOLVED:* I have to add a Q_PROPERTY for the upper containers to read out the contained class(es)'s properties.

Comment: CreMinES, try to read documentation more closely.
Mark answer below as your accepted answer, or write your own answer and mark it as  accepted answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

That is already described in documentation, take a look at [Qt Project -- QML Data Models](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativemodels.html). See "QObjectList-based model", and here is [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/declarative-modelviews-objectlistmodel.html).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the example, but this only works if you have one level QObject* in your model, 
e.g. 'appLog.append(new NfcLogEntry("122345", QUrl("http://www.awesome.com"));'

But I want to have something like: 
'appLog.append(new AppLogEntry(new NfcLogEntry("122345", QUrl("http://www.awesome.com"))));'

Comment: Inherit your `AppLogEntry` from `QObject*`.